# If statement in Java is not working properly

Tags: java, oop

my CODE:

```
public class prob2 {

    public boolean mustChange(int[] a, int n) {  
        boolean ok=true;
        if ( a[n] < a[n+1] ) {
           ok=false;
        }
        return ok;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("n=");
        int n = read.nextInt();
        int a[]= new int[10];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.print("a["+(i+1)+"] =");
            a[i]=read.nextInt();
        }       

        prob2 obj=new prob2();
        System.out.println(obj.mustChange(a,2));
    }
}
```

It always returns TRUE even if my array a={1,2,3}. The if-statement is not working properly.

Comment: You are checking the index of  2 and 3 in the array

Comment: That's because `a[2]>=a[3]`, because `3>=0`.

Comment: I'm trying to compare a[2]=2 and a[3]=3; and thats in the correct order so it must be returning FALSE, NOT TRUE

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed. `a[0]==1`, `a[1]==2` and `a[2]==3`.

Comment: Gut Incognito is right., so, since arrays are zero based,   a[2] == 3 and a[3] == 0. and   3 !< 0

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
System.out.println(obj.mustChange(a,2));
```

here n = 2 in your function
if your array a = {1,2,3};

```
a[2] = 3;
a[n-1] = a[2-1] = a[1] = 2;
```

so, this condition, if(a[2] < a[2+1] which is a[3])
tell me what is the value of a[3]? It's not declared. it's 0 automatically;
so that makes your if statement false,

```
if(a[2] which is 3 < a[3] which is 0) //not true. so 'ok' is never false;
```

means it doesn't get executed.
What you can do, is to change your array initialization like,

```
int a[]= new int[n]; // so if input is 2, array size will be 2, a[0] and a[1].
```

also then your if statement has to be changed as it will hit indexoutofbound because of a[n+1] which won't exist.